# Update qty in shopping cart bounces/redirects to main site

Tags: shopping-cart

Within the shopping cart, when I update qty and click update cart. This results in a bounce/redirection to main page/landing site. This also occurs when I calculate shipping rate within the shopping cart one page checkout.

My Shopping cart setting:

```
System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart > After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart = No.
```

If set to = `yes`, that would take the customer to shopping cart every time they add a product to the shopping cart. I don't want that. Am I missing out something?

Answer (score 1):

That config is correct. After you add product to cart, it should redirect you to the current page. Perhaps you are using an extension which cause this problem. Try to disable third party extensions, one by one, you may find out what is causing the issue.